# QDialog won't stay on top of parent QMainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow, qdialog

I'm trying to use Qt to make an **option dialog that stays on top of the program's main window** (which is a QMainWindow). QDialog seemed like a perfect fit, but clicking the main window would bring it back to the front. However, **I have managed to make two tiny examples: one which works, and another which doesn't** (which is derived from my actual application). I don't know what makes the behavior different between these two examples.

---

The option window in the following example stays on top of the main window:

`test.cpp`

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDialog>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication test(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow *mainWindow = new QMainWindow;
    mainWindow->show();

    QDialog * optionsWindow = new QDialog(mainWindow);
    optionsWindow->show();

    return test.exec();
}
```

`test.pro`

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = test
INCLUDEPATH += .
QT = core gui widgets 

SOURCES += test.cpp
```

---

The option window in the following example does **not** stay on top of the main window:

`TestApp.cpp`

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "MainWindow.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        QApplication testAppGUI(argc, argv);

        MainWindow *mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        mainWindow->show();

        return testAppGUI.exec();
}
```

`MainWindow.hpp`

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_HPP
#define MAINWINDOW_HPP

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "OptionWindow.hpp"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0)
        {
            optionWindow = new OptionWindow(this);
            optionWindow->show();
        }
        OptionWindow *optionWindow;
};

#endif
```

`OptionsWindow.hpp`

```
#ifndef OPTIONWINDOW_HPP
#define OPTIONWINDOW_HPP

#include <QDialog>

class OptionWindow : public QDialog 
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit OptionWindow(QWidget *parent = 0){}
};

#endif
```

`TestApp.pro`

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = TestApp
INCLUDEPATH += .

QT = core gui widgets 

HEADERS +=  MainWindow.hpp \
            OptionWindow.hpp

SOURCES +=  TestApp.cpp
```

---

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26316185/5776736) suggests giving the QDialog a parent, which I do. It also mentions setting the `Qt::Tool` flag, but it could not solve my problem (and the working example above doesn't use it).

[This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26066609/5776736) suggests using a QDockWidget, but it doesn't meet my wanted visual style or expected behavior.

Speaking of which, here's what I expect of my options dialog:

- The options window should always be on top of the main window, but not of the other applications;
- Only the main window shows in the taskbar;
- Minimizing the main window also minimizes the options window, and restoring it also restores the options window (on top of the main window);
- The main window should still be enabled when the options window is open.

I am using QMake 3.1, Qt 5.8.0, g++ 5.4.0 and Xfce 4.12 on Linux Lite 3.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of points...

Firstly, you're not using the `parent` parameter passed to the `OptionWindow` ctor: you need...

```
class OptionWindow: public QDialog {
  Q_OBJECT;
public:
  explicit OptionWindow (QWidget *parent = nullptr)
    : QDialog(parent) /* <-- Added */
  {}
};
```

That issue I understand but... secondly, it appears you need to make sure you call `show` on the parent *before* calling `show` against the `QDialog`.

```
class MainWindow: public QMainWindow {
  Q_OBJECT;
public:
  explicit MainWindow (QWidget *parent = nullptr)
    {
      optionWindow = new OptionWindow(this);
      show(); /* <-- Added */
      optionWindow->show();
    }
  OptionWindow *optionWindow;
};
```

That one I can't really explain -- sorry (although it could be a function of my window manager: fvwm -- I'm on Suse linux using Qt5.8).  Perhaps someone else can chip in and I'll update.

Comment: First point: ah, yes, this is a mistake I made when trying to make the example as tiny as possible, sorry about that.

Second point: **it works!** I'm still very interested in reading an explanation for this, but in the meantime, thank you very much. I have gladly accepted this answer.

Comment: Looks like your second point is related to the window manager or Qt version. [this example](https://pastebin.com/Jfs9352m) satisfies all the OP's conditions when run on  Qt5.6.1/MSVC2013/Windows7. I will try on more platforms when I can.

Comment: You must be right, because this example does not satisfy the conditions on my system. I edited my original post to add that I am using Xfce 4.12 on Linux Lite 3.4. Thank you for your comment.